# $.ajax is not a function, but the jquery library is working

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I see this in the console:

[image: jQuery.ajax is not a function]

And this is my ajax:

```
    $("#aceptar").click(function(){

      dni = $("#dni").val();
      passw = $("#pass").val();

      alert(dni)
      alert(passw)


      $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url:  'credenciales.php',
          dataType : 'html',
          data: {
              dni: dni,
              pass: passw,
          },
          success: function(suc) {

              alert("jaja")

          },
          error: function() {
          alert('An error occurred!');
          }
      });


  })
```

In the php file I only have an echo, but anyway the alert has a "jaja", not the php echo, and still not working.

All my other jQuery code is working without problem. Does this means that only the ajax function is wrong in the library? I have tried with other libraries and im always getting the same error.

Comment: missing the `;` after alert()

Comment: the console error is talking about jQuery.ajax, not about $.ajax. What is line 39? (click on the link at the error to check)

Comment: @Jeff No need to a `;` there. OP is missing at least one other `;` as well. I'd be more concerned about the trailing `,` in `data`. `$.ajax` and `jQuery.ajax` are the same thing unless they've done something interesting or there's a `$` conflict (which doesn't happen too much anymore)

Comment: Which jQuery package are you using?

Comment: Looks like you are looking at the wrong code. Error is somewhere else. Maybe you should check the network tab once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [jQuery download page](http://jquery.com/download/):

> You can also use the slim build, which excludes the ajax and effects modules